# How to check for missing keys in i18n YAML files in a Vue project within IntelliJ

Tags: vuejs2, yaml, internationalization, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I'm working on a Vue project which utilizes i18n for multiple languages. For this, I have several YAML files containing translation keys for various languages, e.g., German, English and French.

I'm looking for an IntelliJ plugin or a another method that can automatically verify if all the keys present in one language file (e.g., German) also exist in the other language files (e.g., English). The goal is to ensure there are no missing translations.

Comment: what about generating a global language json file (e.g English) as a base file and then create all other language file from this ? Only values will be different of translations in each file. Keys will be same.